# How to access file in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I try to use [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/) to build the web application, now I have create a directory as `"/ > home > myid_xxx > mysite > FM"`, and under the `'FM'` directory, there are two files : `demo1.py` and `demo_pickle_file.pkl` .

I try to `cPickle.load(open('demo_pickle_file.pkl','rb'))` in 'demo1.py', but the pythonanywhere console shows :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'demo_pickle_file.pkl'
```

So, how to correctly access the pickle file ?

Comment: make sure your running path is inside of the directory with `demo_pickle_file.pkl`, otherwise you need the entire or relative path.

Comment: As I am a newbie of pythonanywhere, I didn't catch your meaning . Does "make sure your running path is inside of the directory with demo_pickle_file.pkl" mean to put the "demo1.py" and "demo_pickle_file.pkl" in the same folder ? If so, I already done that. If not,  " otherwise you need the entire or relative path", how to do that ? Thanks ..

Comment: Consider printing out `os.getcwd()` to determine where python might be looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the pickle file is in the same directory as`demo1.py`you could use something like the following to find the path to it from the path to the script:

```
import os
import cPickle as pickle

my_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
pickle_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'demo_pickle_file.pkl')

with open(pickle_file_path, 'rb') as pickle_file:
    demo = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

Comment: You can, of course, `print pickle_file_path` to learn what the actual path is to the file.

Comment: i finally hardcode the pickle file's absolute path to solve the issue. I just want to know more about the mechanize to find the file in pythonanywhere.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the hardcoding of paths into code -- either by using the technique shown in my answer or using some kind of configuration file (see the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) module). Of course you'll still need to determine the path to the configuration file itself, so even then the approach shown can come in handy.

Comment: yes, your code is more elegent. i will replace the hardcoded path with that. thanks again..